# Ionic: workaround for sliding tab bug in ionic 1, cannot slide over 5 pages

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

Ionic 1 has a bug where the sliding tab not able to slide more than 5 pages. Whenever it is more than 5 pages, it will return to the 1st page for the 6th slides, 2nd pages for the 7th slides.

How to make the tab 6 able to slide to page 6 and not return to page 1? I suspect it is a bug in ionic.

Any workaround that can fix the issue?

My code as below

Angular.js

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope,$ionicSlideBoxDelegate) {

    $scope.slideIndex = 0;

            // Called each time the slide changes
        $scope.slideChanged = function(index) {
            $scope.slideIndex = index;
            console.log("slide Change");

        $scope.activeSlide = function (index) {
            $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(index);
        };
});
```

template

```
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <title>Ionic Slide Tab</title>

    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
      <h1 class="title">Ionic Slide Tab</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <ion-content>
      <div class="row">
        <ul class="slide-tab">
            <li ng-class="slideIndex == 0 ? 'current':''"><a href="#" ng-click="activeSlide(0)">Tab01</a></li>
            <li ng-class="slideIndex == 1 ? 'current':''"><a href="#" ng-click="activeSlide(1)">Tab02</a></li>
            <li ng-class="slideIndex == 2 ? 'current':''"><a href="#" ng-click="activeSlide(2)">Tab03</a></li>
            <li ng-class="slideIndex == 3 ? 'current':''"><a href="#" ng-click="activeSlide(3)">Tab04</a>

          </li>
          <li ng-class="slideIndex == 4 ? 'current':''"><a href="#" ng-click="activeSlide(4)">Tab05</a></li>
          <li ng-class="slideIndex == 5 ? 'current':''"><a href="#" ng-click="activeSlide(5)">Tab06</a></li> 
        </ul>
        </div>
        <ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideChanged(index)" active-slide="slideIndex" class="padding">
            <ion-slide>
                <h3>Tab 1</h3>
              <p>bye bye.</p>
            </ion-slide>
            <ion-slide>
                <h3>Tab 2</h3>
               <p>bye bye 1</p>
            </ion-slide>
            <ion-slide>
                <h3>Tab 3</h3>
               <p>bye bye2.</p>
            </ion-slide>
            <ion-slide>
                <h3>Tab 4</h3>
               <p>bye bye 3.</p>
            </ion-slide>
           <ion-slide>
                <h3>Tab 5</h3>
               <p>bye bye 4</p>
            </ion-slide>
           <ion-slide>
                <h3>Tab 6</h3>
               <p>bye bye 5.</p>
            </ion-slide>
                 </ion-slide-box>
    </ion-content>

  </body>
</html>
```

css

```
.slide-tab{
    display: table;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #eff0f2;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #00897B;

}

.slide-tab li{
    float: left;
    line-height: 38px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
}

.slide-tab a{
    background-color: #eff0f2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #888;
    font-weight: 500;
    display: block;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #00897B;
}
.current a{
    color: #fff;
    background: #00897B;
}
```